# $fittedとは

Tags: r

こんにちは。
Rの関数についてわからないことがあるので質問します。

lmコマンドで重回帰分析をした後、$fittedで表示される値が、どういう計算で算出されたもので、何を表しているのかを知りたいのです。詳細は画像を参照してください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

この場合，`sd$fitted`で出てきている値は，重回帰分析を実施して算出された予測値となります。そのため，行数と同一の11の値が出力されています。

またこのモデル(`cost~.`)という表現から，従属変数(predicted variable)を`cost`にし，それ以外の`d`に含まれる変数を説明変数(predictor)として投入しています。なので，以下と等価です:

```
sd <- lm(cost~no+area+walk+old, data=d)
```

計算手法については普通の重回帰なので，すぐに調べられると思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。$fittedによって予測値が返ってくるというのは調べて知っていたのです（記載しておらず申し訳ありません）が、予測値とは何の予測値なのでしょうか？area,walk,oldを説明変数とした際のcostの予測値ということでしょうか？

Comment: 回答にも記載していますが，`~.`と説明変数側をピリオドとした場合，データセットの残りの変数全てを投入することになります。なのでno, area, walk, oldの4つが説明変数とした際のcostの予測値となります。

Comment: すいません、そうですね、noも入りますね。重回帰というのは今回の場合一つの目的変数（cost)と四つの説明変数（no,area,walk,old)の11のデータをもとに、y(cost)=ax1(no)+bx2(area)+cx3(walk)+dx4(old)を算出するものですよね？そのデータをもとにした11のcostの予測値というのがよくわからなくて、、、実際にもうcostの値は入力されているのに、「予測」とはどういう意味なのかな、と。

Comment: データセット上のcostは測定値で,fittedはモデル(ax1(no)‌​+bx2(area)+cx3(walk)‌​+dx4(old))から算出された予測値(yhatとよく表現されます)です。この測定値と予測値とのズレが少ないと,このモデルの精度が高い(いい感じのモデル)となり,その当てはまりの良さなどを示す指標がR-squareなどになります。

Comment: なるほど、よくわかりました。モデルを構築する要素の一つとしてcostも入っているにも関わらず、それをもう一度同じ説明変数の数値（no,area,walk,oldの1~11の値）を使って予測するという意味が分かりませんでしたが、$fittedが表すものを理解できました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

ようするに、

```
reg = lm(y ~ x)
reg$fitted + reg$residuals == y
```